# Grouping and rotating data based on "primary key"

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have data that's been generated by my course interface that exports into excel like so:

StudentID   CourseNumber    Grade
1111111 CRSE1   59%
1111111 CRSE2   87%
1111111 CRSE3   79%
1111111 CRSE4   64%
1111112 CRSE1   63%
1111112 CRSE2   69%
1111112 CRSE3   89%
1111112 CRSE4   94%

I am trying to figure out a way for excel to display the information like so:

StudentID   CRSE1   CRSE2   CRSE3   CRSE4
1111111 59% 87% 79% 64%
1111112 63% 69% 89% 94%

Basically, I want the query to take each instance of a course code and rotate it into its own column, but grouped by the StudentID number.

Is there any way to do this without installing thirdParty software.
I have tried this multiple times using PowerQuery and PoverPivot but no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your data in the question are smooshed together, so I'm not sure if that's your intent or a copy/paste issue. Are you trying to go from one long row of data to another long row of data?

If that's NOT the case and your data have rows, then a simple pivot table works...

[image]